# How to load Spring application context with Cucumber runner

Tags: java, spring, junit, automation, cucumber

My goal is running Cucumber scenarios while using Spring for objects creation and wiring. As far as I understood (from some Cucumber books), the Cucumber runner should be responsible for loading the application context as long as the path configured properly.

For example, if I have a runner Java class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"classpath:xxx_features"}, 
                 glue = {"com.package.name"})

public class FunctionalDevIT {
}
```

then Cucumber runner will **automatically** scan and initialize all the beans that it will find so I **won't** have to load the application context manually as well as get beans one by one from the context.

Currently, just to get my head around the concept, I have a created the most basic configuration that consists of three Java classes:

1. Runner class (as described above)
2. Beans Class - the class that contains the beans

   ```
   @Component
   public class BeansClass {

       @Bean
       public void test1() {
           System.out.println("test1!");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Main class - the class that uses the beans defined in the Beans Class

   ```
   @ContextConfiguration("classpath:/cucumber.xml")
   public class MainClass {

       @Autowired
       private BeansClass testclass;

       @Before
       public void navigate() {
           testclass.test1();
       }
   }
   ```

At the moment that approach doesn't work for me and I get the `NullPointerException` when I try to call the `testclass.test1()` method in the Main Class which means that the context wasn't loaded after all.

Am I missing some configuration or perhaps my whole understanding of how that is supposed to be working is wrong?

**P.S.** All my files are currently in the same package.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding and additional configuration class that has been annotated with `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration`, so something like this:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
    . . . 
}
```

Then I used this class in `ConfigurationClass` in the main class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebDriverConfiguration.class)
public class MainClass {
    . . .
}
```